# Would you get electrocuted if you touched a car battery?

Tags: batteries, automotive, electricity

Lets say that you have a connected car battery. If you remove the negative lead first and then touched it would the current go through you to the earth (GND)?

What is i then attached a wire which is touching the ground to the negative battery terminal?

Comment: There's no complete circuit, so no. The car battery is isolated from ground.

Comment: Ok so, if i then attached a wire from the earth to the negative terminal would i get electrocuted assuming the voltage hire enough?

Comment: Ok so, if i then attached a wire from the earth to the negative terminal would i get electrocuted assuming the voltage hire enough?

Comment: @pipe. Not quiet the same question as the past one, so a more complete answer was needed.

Comment: Electrocuted means "injure or kill (someone) by electric shock". So yes, it can happen, but usually only if the skin breaks. I was working on a car once, and the thick sharp ends of the wiring pierced opposite sides of my index finger. Within seconds, a sparkly tip of index finger, and smell of burning flesh filled the car. My finger survived, but I've always been wary of sharp wire ends ever since.

Comment: It might be painful on your tongue or between eyelids, but one finger no.

Answer (score 2):

In a word-NO.

First of all 12 volts is way below the UL (USA) threshold for minimum shock value which is 36 VAC or 48 VDC.

Second, your car or truck is an isolated system provided by the rubber in your tires.

Thirdly, todays vehicles have surge protection built in so starting the vehicle does not cause thousands of volt to appear on the 12 volt power feeds as it did in the past century.

Worst that could happen is that you are working on your vehicle during a thunderstorm. If lightning hits your vehicle and you are standing next to it to work on it then it would be a shock by lightning. Avoid doing this if at all possible, as it could be fatal.

Comment: Ok, if i removed the negative lead from the battery, held on to it (im standing on ground) and then attached a wire from the ground to the negative terminal. Will i be electrocuted assuming high voltage?

Comment: @zenarthra At that point I'd wonder why you're so intent on getting shocked.

Comment: @Felthry I die for science

Comment: @Felthry Its actually quite interesting if you think about it though. If i did get electrocuted, what would be the radius in which i would still get electrocuted. If the wire touching the earth and negative terminal of battery were 10m away from me, would i still get electrocuted?

Comment: @zenarthra. If you touch a voltage that has a earth ground reference and it is way above 48 VDC or 36 VAC, say ten times much, you will get a **BAD** shock and burn. I hope that answers your question, and that you **DO NOT** actually try it.